# Como mostrar caracteres acentuados no Visual Studio 2017 usando C++?

Tags: c++, utf-8, unicode, visual-studio-2017

Fiz essa pergunta um tempo atrás, mas estava ruim então apaguei e estou refazendo com mais detalhes.

O meu problema é o seguinte: Quando uso acentuação no Visual Studio ele retorna caracteres estranhos. Isso só acontece quando compilo usando o Visual Studio, quando uso o Code::Blocks a saída é normal.

Eis o código:

```
#include "stdafx.h" //essa linha somente no Visual Studio
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <clocale>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    cout << "ÁÉÍÓÚ" << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Eis as saídas:

**Visual Studio 2017:**

*Ã?Ã%Ã?Ã"Ãs*

**Code::Blocks 16.01:**

*ÁÉÍÓÚ*

Já tentei usar `setlocale` tentei usar o comando chcp 850, 65001 e 1200 dessa forma: `system("chcp xxx"`) onde **xxx** é o código.

Mudei a fonte para Lucida Consoles, também não funcionou.

Tentei mudar a source e o executável para UTF-8 via linha de comando com /source-charset:utf-8 /execution-charset:utf-8 e não funcionou.

Tem uma opção para mudar o registro mas isso é ridículo. Além do mais no Code::Blocks funciona tranquilamente, apenas adicionando `setlocale`.

Informações adicionais:

OS: Windows 10 Home

Já usei no `setlocale` " ", "English", e outros mais...

Alguma sugestão/ideia?

Comment: Encontrei a solução, criei um projeto vazio e funcionou, além de ficar com menos arquivos como o header stdafx.h. Não sei como fechar a pergunta, se alguém souber por favor sinta-se a vontade, obrigado a todos que disponibilizaram seu tempo.

Answer (score 1):

A chamada de `setlocale( LC_ALL, "" );` (com o segundo parametro em branco), faz com que o locale padrão do programa seja setado conforme as variáveis do seu ambiente, que *certamente* utiliza o encoding `UTF-8` como padrão:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

int main(void)
{
    setlocale( LC_ALL, "" );

    std::wcout  <<  L"ÁÉÍÓÚ"  <<  std::endl;
}
```

A codificação `UTF-8` cobre praticamente todos os alfabetos existentes, tornando a especificação da linguagem um detalhe dispensável.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>


int main(){

    setlocale( LC_ALL, "" );

    std::wstring ch = L"你好世界";
    std::wstring gk = L"γειά σου κόσμος";
    std::wstring jp = L"こんにちは世界";
    std::wstring ko = L"여보세요 세계";
    std::wstring pt = L"Olá mundo!";
    std::wstring ru = L"Здравствулте мир!";

    std::wcout << L"Chinês    : " << ch << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"Grego     : " << gk << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"Japonês   : " << jp << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"Coreano   : " << ko << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"Português : " << pt << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"Russo     : " << ru << std::endl;

}
```

Saída:

```
Chinês    : 你好世界
Grego     : γειά σου κόσμος
Japonês   : こんにちは世界
Coreano   : 여보세요 세계
Português : Olá mundo!
Russo     : Здравствулте мир!
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Eu sei, o que não estava entendendo era porque não funcionava nenhuma forma de mudar o padrão unicode, mas com o projeto em branco `setlocale` funciona corretamente, não sei se isso é um bug, mas quando eu crio um projeto **Prompt de Comando**, não consigo mudar o unicode, e também tenho que incluir a header `"stdafx.h"`.

Comment: O seu prompt de comando certamente não interpreta UTF-8.

Comment: Aí é que está o curioso: No Code::Blocks funciona normalmente, também quando crio um projeto vazio no Visual Studio. Somente o template padrão é que não aceita de forma alguma `setlocale`...

Comment: @uggorim Verifique a codificação dos arquivos que o `Visual Studio` está gerando! Certamente não são arquivos codificados em `UTF-8`!